# How to parse engineering notation in Java

Tags: java, parsing

Is there a simple way to parse numbers in the engineering notation (1.2K, 120m, ...etc) to double value using pure Java or Apache commons library. I'm working on a code that uses the code found [here](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/java/engNotation.html). I'm planing to implement my own solution. The goal is to reuse existing solution included in Java framework. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: `I'm not satisfied with that solution` - you might want to elaborate _why_ you're not satisfied with that.

Comment: Can you give us an example of why that solution isn't working for your use case?

Comment: Could you please include the snippets of code from the link? Links have a tendency to break over time.

Comment: @brso05 that's why I asked the question

Comment: If there was a "very simple way" we wouldn't have IEEE754 now, would we.

Comment: @Shark [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) != [engineering notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation)

Comment: Questions phrased as "what is the best way to do X" are generally off-topic for SO. And as asked, yours is a tad broad. I'd suggest providing some code showing what you have tried, as well as a more complete selection of example input and output values. This would add some value to this question for other users as well since it has a potentially useful answer already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do when writing your own solution: use a lenient number format to parse the number part, get the position that parser stopped at and and use the rest of the input to look up a factor in a map.

Example:

```
public static double convert(String number) {

  //this should be defined outside and is here just for simplicity reasons
  Map<String, Double> mapping = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  mapping.put( "k", 1000.0 );
  mapping.put( "m", 0.001 );

  //Use a specified Locale or otherwise the results would depend on your system locale
  NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance( Locale.ENGLISH );
  ParsePosition p = new ParsePosition( 0 );

  Number n = f.parse( number, p  );
  String suffix = number.substring( p.getIndex() );
  Double factor = mapping.get( suffix );

  return n.doubleValue() * factor;
```

}

Usage:

```
System.out.println(convert("123.453k") );
System.out.println(convert("-3412m") );
```

Output:

```
123453.0
-3.412
```

Comment: Thanks, that's better.

Comment: Not bad, but how does this even handle cases such as `1.8701E123` ?

Comment: Oh how I like unjustified downvotes ;)

Comment: @Shark well, you could handle that special case separately, e.g. look for the `E` then parse the exponent and call `Math.pow(10, exponent)`. My code is meant to provide a starting point, not a full solution. Besides that, `xEy` wouldn't fit the term "engineering notation" :)

Comment: @Shark just read that article again and realized that `xEy` is engineering notation as well. My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/b65Rzr)

```
import java.util.regex.*;

enum EngineeringNotation{
  yocto( 'y', 1e-24 ),
  zepto( 'z', 1e-21 ),
  atta ( 'a', 1e-18 ),
  femto( 'f', 1e-15 ),
  pico ( 'p', 1e-12 ),
  nano ( 'n', 1e-9 ),
  micro( 'μ', 1e-6 ),
  milli( 'm', 1e-3 ),
  unit ( null, 1e0 ),
  kilo ( 'k', 1e3 ),
  mega ( 'M', 1e6 ),
  giga ( 'G', 1e9 ),
  terra( 'T', 1e12 ),
  peta ( 'P', 1e15 ),
  exa  ( 'E', 1e18 ),
  zetta( 'Z', 1e21 ),
  yotta( 'Y', 1e24 );

  final Character symbol;
  final double multiplier;

  private EngineeringNotation( final Character symbol, final double multiplier ){
    this.symbol     = symbol;
    this.multiplier = multiplier;
  }

  public Character getSymbol(){ return symbol; }
  public double getMultiplier(){ return multiplier; }

  private static final Pattern REGEX;

  static {
    final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append( "^([+-]?[1-9]\\d*\\.?\\d*|[+-]?0?\\.\\d+)(?:([" );
    for ( final EngineeringNotation e : values() )
      if ( e.getSymbol() != null )
        buffer.append( e.getSymbol() );
    buffer.append( "]?)|E([+-]?[1-9]\\d*))$" );
    REGEX = Pattern.compile( buffer.toString() );
  }

  public static Double parse( final String value ){
    final Matcher m = REGEX.matcher( value );
    if ( !m.matches() )
        return null;
    Double result = Double.parseDouble( m.group(1) );
    if ( m.group(3) != null )
      return result * Math.pow( 10, Integer.parseInt( m.group(3) ) );
    if ( m.group(2) == null )
      return result; // Units
    final Character c = m.group(2).charAt(0);
    for ( final EngineeringNotation e : values() )
      if ( e.getSymbol() == c )
        return result * e.getMultiplier();
    return null;
  }

  private static String doubleToString( final double value ){
    if ( value == (long) value )
        return String.format( "%d", (long) value );
    return String.format( "%s", value );
  }

  public static String toEngineeringNotation(
      final double value,
      final EngineeringNotation notation
  ){
    if ( notation == null || notation == unit )
        return doubleToString( value );
    return doubleToString( value / notation.getMultiplier() ) + notation.getSymbol();
  }

  public static String toScientificNotation(
      final double value
  ){
    final long exponent = (long) Math.floor( Math.log10( Math.abs( value ) ) );
    return doubleToString( value / Math.pow( 10, exponent ) ) + 'E' + exponent;
  }

  public static String toEngineeringNotation( final double value ){
    final double abs = Math.abs( value );
    double multiplier;
    for ( final EngineeringNotation e : values() )
    {
      multiplier = e.getMultiplier();
      if ( multiplier < abs && abs < multiplier * 1000 )
        return toEngineeringNotation( value, e );
    }
    return toScientificNotation( value );
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    final String[] parseTests = {
        "1.23M",
        "1.23E",
        "1.23E5",
        "1.23E+5",
        "-0.123E-28"
    };
    for ( final String test : parseTests )
      System.out.println( test + " parses to: " + Double.toString( parse( test ) ) );

    final double[] formatTests = {
        1234e18,
        -12.34e-26,
        100,
        0.1
    };

    for ( final double test : formatTests )
      System.out.println( Double.toString( test ) + " formats as " + toEngineeringNotation( test ) );
  }
}
```